# Access to content of a page instead of cookie popup (SELENIUM PYTHON)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, popup

For some days I am searching a way to solve my problem but I've not found anything that worked. I am creating a program that scrapes website and I want to collect all the content of 'p' and 'hn' tags. My only problem is that on some website, a cookie popup appears and does not enable me to scrape correctly.

And the thing is that I scrape every type of website so it means that it is not always the same pattern and accepting by xpath / CSSselector is almost impossible.

I have tried many things, like searching for buttons and then looking if there is 'accept' inside of it :

```
try:
btns = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
btntxt = [elem.text for elem in btns]
print(btntxt)
btntitle = [elem.get_attribute('title') for elem in btns]
for i in range(0, len(btns)-1):
    if btn[i].find("accept") != -1:
        btns[i].click()
except NoSuchElementException:
pass
```

I have also tried to accept all cookies but it does not help me to close the popup :

```
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies_list:
   cookies_dict = {}
   cookies_dict['name'] = cookie['name']
   cookies_dict['value'] = cookie['value']
   driver.add_cookie(cookies_dict)
```

Does anyone has another idea to accept cookies and close these popups ? Or another solution to sort of ignore completely the popup ?
Thanks in advance hope i've been clear enough !